# What is the importance of post-buffer in uwsgi or nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver, uwsgi

I've  a python bottle app configured over nginx and uwsgi, where I'm finding it hard to understand **uwsgi post-buffering** option,

Could someone explain me whats the purpose of **post-buffering**?

What the maximum number of bytes which can be set for this option..?

I want to submit, around 100MB payload over one of the POST endpoints, can we set the post-buffering to support this value..?

Is there any other thing needs to be taken care of when we are opting for this option..?

### Configuration

CentOS 6.8

Python 2.6

uWSGI (2.0.11.2)

nginx/1.11.5

Comment: http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2017-April/008694.html

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19615

Answer (score 1):

basically, if an upload or an request is extremely slow, and you only have like 3 or 4 workers available, all of the workers will busy doing slow but meaningless data receiving work.

If you have a post-buffer, then good news, uWSGi will gather enough data first, then forward to the worker of python code to do the actual business.